# Docker socket crash after stack up

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, swarm, docker-stack

I trying to deploy docker stack, that includes my development environment. But in random cases I have next error:

```
> failed to create service < service_name >: Cannot connect to the
> Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon
> running?
```

Next I restart docker daemon. Sometimes it requires to kill docker processes and shims. I deleting old stack and build again. Some times docker successfully finishes build, but socket crashes on the starting stage.

Also all containers work properly when I starting it in regular mode, without swarm or stack. It is not work exactly inside swarm.

I have used next command to build:

```
> $ docker stack deploy dev-env-stc -c docker-compose.yml
```

Environment run in Antergos Linux(Arch).

Layout is like at the diagram
[image]

Nginx container and docker networks created using commands:

```
>$ docker run --detach --name nginx-main --net dev-env-ext --ip 10.20.20.10 --publish 80:80 --publish 443:443 --volume /env-vol/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro --volume /env-vol/nginx/www:/usr/var/www --volume /env-vol/nginx/logs:/usr/var/logs --volume /env-vol/nginx/run:/usr/var/run --volume /env-vol/ssl:/usr/var/ssl:ro nginx-webserver 
>
> $ docker network create --driver=bridge --attachable --ipv6 --subnet fd19:eb5a:3d2f:f15d::/48 --subnet 10.20.20.0/24 --gateway 10.20.20.1 dev-env-ext
> 
> $ docker network create --driver=bridge --attachable --ipv6 --subnet fd19:eb5a:3e30:f15d::/48 --subnet 10.20.30.0/24 --gateway 10.20.30.1 dev-env-int
> 
> $ docker network create --driver=overlay --attachable --ipv6 --subnet fd19:eb5a:3c1e:f15d::/48 --subnet 10.20.40.0/24 --gateway 10.20.40.1 dev-env-swarm
> 
> $ docker network connect dev-env-swarm --ip=10.20.40.10 nginx-main
>
> $ docker network connect dev-env-int --ip=10.20.30.10 nginx-main
```

My docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.6'
volumes:
  postgres-data:
    driver: local
  redis-data:
    driver: local
networks:
  dev-env-swarm:
    external: true
services:
  gitlab:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
    hostname: gitlab.testenv.top
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    ports:
      - 22:22
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "https://localhost:443"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: vip
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.50"
          memory: 4096M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.10"
          memory: 512M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 300s
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - gitlab.testenv.top
    dns: 
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 8.8.8.8
    volumes:
      - /env-vol/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
      - /env-vol/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
      - /env-vol/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
    external_links:
      - nginx-main
  redis:
    env_file: .env
    image: redis:3.2.6-alpine
    hostname: redis.testenv.top
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:6379"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.20"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.05"
          memory: 128M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    volumes:
      - redis-data:/var/lib/redis
    command: redis-server --appendonly yes
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - redis.testenv.top
    dns:
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 8.8.8.8
  redisco:
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    hostname: redisco.testenv.top
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    depends_on:
      - redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8081"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.20"
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.05"
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - redisco.testenv.top
    dns: 
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 8.8.8.8
    environment: 
      REDIS_PORT: 6379
      REDIS_HOST: redis.testenv.top
  plantuml:
    image: plantuml/plantuml-server:tomcat
    hostname: plantuml.testenv.top
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.20"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.05"
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - plantuml.testenv.top
    dns: 
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 8.8.8.8
  portainer-agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    expose:
      - 9001
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.20"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.05"
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    environment:
      AGENT_CLUSTER_ADDR: tasks.portainer-agent
      AGENT_PORT: 9001
      LOG_LEVEL: debug
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - portainer-agent.testenv.top
    deploy:
      mode: global
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer
    command: -H tcp://tasks.portainer-agent:9001 --tlsskipverify
    depends_on:
      - portainer-agent
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:9000"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.20"
          memory: 2024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.05"
          memory: 512M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    volumes:
      - /env-vol/portainer/data:/data
    hostname: portainer.testenv.top
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - portainer.testenv.top
    dns: 
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 8.8.8.8 
  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    hostname: pgadmin.testenv.top
    external_links: 
      - nginx-main
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost"]
      interval: 1m30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 60s
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.20"
          memory: 1024M
        reservations:
          cpus: "0.05"
          memory: 256M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
        delay: 20s
        max_attempts: 3
        window: 60s
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: email@example.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: PASWORD
    networks:
      dev-env-swarm:
        aliases:
          - pgadmin.testenv.top
    dns: 
      - 10.10.10.10
      - 8.8.8.8
    volumes:
      - /env-vol/pgadmin:/var/lib/pgadmin
```

Comment: From your title and initial post, it sounds like the Docker daemon is crashing.  That doesn't sound like something SO can help with.  Some of the links on https://www.docker.com/docker-community might be better places to ask.

Comment: I've got the same problem: deploying an additional stack crashes the docker daemon on a node.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with socket was from wrong Python installation from sources and manual installation of libs. Looks like I have installed incompatible versions. When I have reinstalled Python from repository this problem wasn't appear again.